Occasional mouse freezes on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I have a desktop PC with AMD CPU and GPU. It has 16 GB RAM. While using browser or other applications, my mouse sometimes freezes for like 2 seconds and goes back to normal. It happens on both Wayland and Xorg.
"Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost."
I sometimes get that when I check syslog at the time freezing happens.
I connect my mouse via USB.

You have not said how the mouse connects to the computer. Is it USB or Unified Receiver or Bluetooth or something else. Please use the edit function and add this info to the question.

What is the ram usage when it occurs? Please keep system monitor open, and check the ram usage when the issue occurs the next time

Added how the mouse connects to the PC. I'll try to check ram usage when this happens. I check it from time to time but I haven't seen anything weird going on.
